# authentication to google by openid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, openid

I have Rails 3.0.9 app,
in my sessions_controller I have

```
def open_id_authentication(domain=nil)
  domain = "" if domain.nil?
  complete_identity_url = IDENTITY_URL + domain
  authenticate_with_open_id(complete_identity_url, OPENID_OPTS) do |openid_result, identity_url, registration|
    if openid_result.successful?
      matches = /\/a\/(.*)\/o8/.match(params["openid.op_endpoint"])
      google_domain = matches[1] if matches[1]
      if valid_account?(google_domain)
        account = Account.find_by_google_domain(google_domain)
        session[:account_id] = account.id
        self.current_user = User.openid_registration(registration, identity_url, account.id)
      else
        flash[:error] = t('flash.session.domain_not_registered')
        redirect_to accounts_path
        return false
    end

        redirect_back_or_default(THIS_path)
    else
      flash[:error] = t('flash.open_id.authentication_failed')
      redirect_to accounts_path
    end
  end
end
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'ruby-openid', '2.1.8'
gem 'ruby-openid-apps-discovery', '1.2.0'
gem 'open_id_authentication', '1.0.0'
```

I'm getting error in row

```
matches = /\/a\/(.*)\/o8/.match(params["openid.op_endpoint"])
```

because params doesn't contain such key.

Before, the app was Rails 2.3.14 and three listed gems were plugins. It worked fine.
Someone have issued such thing, help please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved that by replacing

```
matches = /\/a\/(.*)\/o8/.match(params["openid.op_endpoint"])
```

by

```
matches = /\/a\/(.*)\/o8/.match(request.env[Rack::OpenID::RESPONSE].endpoint.server_url)
```